# Page For Specific Posts

Tags: theme-development

Im trying to find a way to choose in which page I want my posts to be published in. I have been trying to manipulate the theme-files and to write new functions. But so far without any success.

Anyone out there who could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not really how Posts work in WordPress. If you want pages with lists of specific posts, I suggest using categories and tags. Each tag and category automatically gets a page that lists the posts that belong to it.

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me alot.